# Sql generation / Change tracking Logic

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am going bonkers on this. I am new to linq to sql and didn't quite grasp linq's change tracking concepts yet. I have a situation where I have to do loads of db stuff in a single DataContext. I am noticing lots of weird stuff like:

```
//Control flows to this statement, but I dont see
//corresponding sql generated in the log.
//However if I instead change it to db.ExecuteCommand("delete from mytable")
//that shows up fine in the log

db.mytable.deleteAllOnSubmit(db.mytable);
```

This is only part of the story. But I want to know if there ever will be a case where correct sql is not generated? Can one possibility be, I am trying to delete all the rows from the table, but later on, I try to insert same exact rows again and linq somehow detects this ignored delete-reinsert to avoid unnecessary work?

Comment: Updated the answer.  Curious to hear about your findings :-)

Comment: Seeing your new comments I have updated my answer with some additional advice.  Hope it helps! The quick solution to what you want to achieve with L2S is to insert an additional `SubmitChanges` after the L2S `deletion' in the code of your question.  This will ensure the corresponding DELETE statements are generated and sent to the SQL server and the pk-fk relationships with 'on cascade delete' will do their thing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that operations such as `deleteAllOnSubmit` are not translated to SQL and executed on the spot.

**ITable.DeleteAllOnSubmit Method:** 
Puts all entities from the collection into a pending delete state.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable.deleteallonsubmit.aspx

The deletion will not happen until you do:

```
  db.SubmitChanges();
```

---

**Update 1:**

No delete statement will occur if your table is empty.  Moreover, `SubmitChanges` is by its specification allowed  to try to be clever in your particular scenario, though if you had triggers you thought would be executed you would be disappointed.  If you have delete/insert triggers you might want to consider having a SubmitChanges after the LINQ 'deletions'.

**DataContext.SubmitChanges Method:**  Computes the set of modified objects to be inserted, updated, or deleted, and executes the appropriate commands to implement the changes to the database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx

**Note:** This update was made after the OP checked and verified that the table was empty at the time `SubmitChanges()` was called.  At a later point the OP checked and verified that this also happens when data is deleted from the table only to be replaced with identical data.

---

**Update 2:**

@Brian Good to hear you are making progress with this stuff :-)

**General Advice:**

1. Avoid mixing ExecuteCommand's with L2S unless you *know* what you are doing;`ExecuteCommand`'s may change the state of the database under L2S's feet and give you (*well deserved!*) headaches!  If you are not afraid of such headaches you can try to delete the rows with `ExecuteCommand` before L2S accesses the table (faster but you need to get it right).  If you are afraid of such headaches and just want the 'on delete' events to be fired on the SQL server  just do a `SubmitChanges` after the L2S `deletion' in the code of your question.
2. You could rely on fine-grained L2S interaction with the database with `SubmitChanges`, but it in the long run it will be much better to realise that you are given a tool to interact with the database in an entirely new way. L2S tries to be clever and that is not bad.  Use it to your advantage! In this particular case it has saved you some unnecessary delete/insert operations, in effect optimising your code, without you having to do anything.  Is it wrong to try to be that clever?  Yes, if you think of operations individually and no if you think that all it tries to do is update the DB with the net effect of your code's actions.

Comment: I understand that. I meant, it doesn't show any delete statements in the log even AFTER db.SubmitChanges()

Comment: AHA. apparently it is. But I can swear linq was acting weird even with data in the table. Let me try to reproduce and will get back here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Deleted instead of editing my previous comment, sorry.  I had asked Brian if the table happened to be empty.  In this case SubmitChanges will have no delete statements to send to the SQL server.

Comment: Let me ask a quick side question. So then it is not advisable to mix linq with normal sql statements using ExecuteCommand? As in, can I in between do stuff like db.ExecutCommand("delete from mytable") or ("Update my table") etc?

Comment: I am not done with this yet, will be back, but just read your update, so you mean, things like this can happen: In the same db context, I delete a row (which has dependent rows in other tables somewhere -foreign keys with 'on delete cascade') and add it back again (but I don't want the dependent rows in other tables when I re added my main row in original table), you are saying, a delete statement might not be executed at all, and so no dependent rows will ever be deleted from other secondary tables?

Comment: So looks like if I try to delete rows but then try to add them back again in same context, linq nullifies those two sets of operations and won't generate any related sql at all. That explains why I sometimes do not see sql chunks in generated sql, when I expect it to. Thanks. Now I am back to learning linq :-)

Comment: Thank You! I basically want to say blank out the entire database if a certain condition is met, and repopulate the db with new stuff from web api. This whole process is my 'unit of work' unfortunately. I got to carefully use ExecuteCommand to delete rows from all tables. The DeleteAllOnSubmit approach will generate huge number of delete statements which I want to avoid. Thank you so much for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

> So then it is not advisable to mix linq with normal sql statements
>   using ExecuteCommand?

Definetely not if you intend to rely on the change tracking mechanism. Your datacontext will turn 'stale'.

**Update**
If you stick to 'pure' L2S, all the inserts/updates/deletes will be converted to the proper SQL. And as long as you do it with one SubmitChanges it will also be done in one transaction. So it is not that bad after all. You just cannot mix it with ExecuteCommand because it is will be impossible for L2S to track the changes that are caused by for example a stored procedure without scanning the entire database... Not what you want.

Basic rule: create one DC for each 'unit of work' and do only ONE SubmitChanges for it. With that, you will be fine using L2s

Comment: That blows! So we need to be real careful with using linq, because there is no gaurantee that some linq statements will ever get converted to sql, linq can just ignore them if it thinks actions are redundant? So what are my options if I want to update my database based on an (web) api, so multiple url hits, but I want the whole process to be atomic? My main problems with linq looks like is because I am trying to avoid doing multiple submitchanges and trying to handle too much stuff in one submitchanges()

Comment: No, you just have to stick to the ORM-model. If you mix it with Executecommand, Linq has no way to determine the consequences in terms of entities. You can execute a stored procedure => how can L2S determine the impact in the object world.

Comment: But my issue is, say I have a main table and secondary tables (pk-fk relationships with 'on cascade delete' s). In a single DataContext I want to delete a row from main table, and say add it back conditionally. Linq 'clever'ly optimizes and nullifies my delete-reinsert and doesn't do anything. causing my secondary tables' data to remain still. That is wrong right? What is the workaround? Handle all secondary deletes manually? It is not correct to rely on DRI to do our bidding when linq is involvede?

Comment: You are mixing the ORM and the database world. Linq does not 'know' about the cascading deletes.